# Ordering objects by calculating the sum of fields on a foreign key Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Say I had some models defined as such:

```
Class Owner(models.Model):
    pass

Class Item(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    owners = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name="items")
```

How would I go about sorting Owners based off of the sum of the value of their items, ideally as a QuerySet that I could pass onto a template like `Owner.objects.order_by('-valueofItems')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ORM [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) together with [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Owner.objects.annotate(total_value=Sum('item_value')).order_by('-total_value')
```

Comment: Works but with `Owner.objects.annotate(total_value=Sum('items__value')).order_by('-total_value')`